# sed + replace value default in grub.conf

Tags: linux, perl, grub, sed, regular-expressions

I want to change the default value on all machines to default=0

default value could be any integer number

how to set in the sed syntax that default could be any number

my example ( not working )

```
for server_ip in $all_servers
   do
   ssh $server_ip  "sed -i s'/default=[0-9]/default=0/g' /etc/grub.conf"
done
```

example of grub.conf

```
  more /etc/grub.conf
  # grub.conf generated by anaconda
  #
  # Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this     file
  # NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
  #          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
  #          root (hd0,0)
  #          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/rootvg/slash
  #          initrd /initrd-version.img
  #boot=/dev/cciss/c0d0
  default=2
```

Comment: How does this not work ? What error messages do you see ?

Comment: hi lain , this is my mistake , I not tested because I was thinking that my syntax is wrong , I test the script and script is working fine , do you have the ability to delete the question , because I dont have

Comment: Your script doesn't work as written because for example `all-servers` is an illegal variable name.

Comment: If you have so many serers that you need to run scripts on many of them in this manner, you shouldn't be running scripts in this manner. There are a number of config management systems such as puppet or ansible; now would be a very good time to look at them.

Answer (score 2):

The script in the [original version](https://serverfault.com/revisions/801100/1) of your question contained an error in that the variable name `all-servers` is illegal. The `-` character is not allowed in a shell variable name.

Valid characters are [A-Za-z0-9_].